# Magento EBS payment gateway - upon redirection shows 404 page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, payment-gateway, redirect

I have developed a store and using EBS payment gateway for netbanking. It was working fine but suddenly it started showing a 404 page not found error upon redirection. After clicking confirm order the customer is never directed to the EBS page but remains on the site with the page not found message!

I've checked the EBS key, Magento base urls etc, what else can i do?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was an issue with the i-speed plugin. I just put 'secureebs' into ignored URL section if that helps anyone